# Examples of Token Vesting logic for ERC20 Token Launch

Tags: tokens, erc-20

We are trying to implement a token contract in ethereum which will have some tokenomics strategies built-in, for eg. Some tokens will be pre allocated to certain addresses on contract deployment itself.. Some tokens will follow a vesting schedule before unlocking to be withdrawn to certain address, while also an inflation logic for a chunk of tokens.. Do we have any example contracts as such in solidity that deals with such tokenomics strategies?

Answer (score 6):

For vesting strategies you can check the Ethereum's Stackexchange question [Time Lock and vesting smart contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/62126/time-lock-and-vesting-smart-contract) with what the author describe as a

> really quick and untested scribble to give you some ideas. Starting with the ERC20 interface by openzeppelin

Also in Openzeppelin there is a smart contract called [VestingWallet.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/finance/VestingWallet.sol) that

> handles the vesting of Eth and ERC20 tokens for a given beneficiary. Custody of multiple tokens
> can be given to this contract, which will release the token to the beneficiary following a given vesting schedule.
> The vesting schedule is customizable through the {vestedAmount} function.

There is a [medium post](https://medium.com/cardstack/building-a-token-vesting-contract-b368a954f99) about the Cardstack token vesting strategy influenced by the OpenZeppelin implementation.

There is also a youtube video from the Dapp Academy called [Create Token Vesting with Smart Contracts - #12 Real World ICO on Ethereum](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NxzJiGPyyLw)

Regarding an inflation logic you can start by checking the [OpenZeppelin's MintableToken implementation](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/MintableToken.sol) and a solution like [AION](https://www.aion.ethpantheon.com/index.html#howitworks) to schedule calls to the contract at a point in the future

I hope this answer your question, there are smart contracts with various tokenomics strategies out there.